# Rails Adding Pagination inside tab content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, pagination

I will like to add in pagination inside my tab content but i am quite new to rails and web development. Thus, need some guide to this. 
Example: I have 3 tabs. In tab 1, i will want to be able to navigate around between say 3 pages.

Thanks

Comment: have a look at the will_paginate gem - https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the gem will_paginate: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

It will make your life a lot easier. Since you are using paginations inside individual tabs, you will need ajax. take a look at this also:

https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination/wiki/Adding-AJAX-to-will_paginate

Answer (score 0):

You may need use AJAX and the gem will_paginate, check this out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax